# Dynamic Laravel Style Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I'm using Laravel's Facade architecture (the AliasLoader class and Facade class) to create facades for my app.  All is working well initially, I add the aliases to the loader and register them, create a facade class and boom, facades everywhere.

But now I'm trying to clean up my model calls.

Currently I'm loading the model `Theme::model('sale/order')` like so, this creates a `model_sale_order` object on the container. I'd like to also add a facade on the fly so that I can call the model more elegantly `SaleOrder::getOrders($customer_id)`

Adding the alias is no big deal, but where to point it? There is no facade file to point this too.

Is it possible to set up a class that could dynamically detect which object we're looking for from the container?

```
class DynamicFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'my.dynamically.created.object';
    }
}
```

Comment: This ended up to be impossible, closing the question.